# Change the values of a dictionary from lists to scalar values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary (in fact, a dictionary of dictionaries), the values of which are lists of a single element. Is there a quick way to change the corresponding lists to scalar values?

```
mydata = {0: {u'AM019J4O': [u'XAIXMZ2H'],
              u'BPJZMDRJ': [u'EKDZTAZJ'],
              u'CMNH1UAS': [u'EP8S0STW']},
          1: {u'AM019J4O': [u'X47VO9R8'],
              u'BPJZMDRJ': [u'EK5GPG4R'],
              u'CMNH1UAS': [u'RNANJHMK']}}
```

What I want is

```
mydata = {0: {u'AM019J4O': u'XAIXMZ2H',
              u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EKDZTAZJ',
              u'CMNH1UAS': u'EP8S0STW'},
          1: {u'AM019J4O': u'X47VO9R8',
              u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EK5GPG4R',
              u'CMNH1UAS': u'RNANJHMK'}}
```

Comment: `{k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for k,v in mydata.items():
    mydata[k] = {k1: v1[0] for k1, v1 in v.items()}
```

It's a nested `dict` so iterate through it and extract the single element from the list.

**Working**

```
In [2]: for k,v in mydata.items():
   ...:         mydata[k] = {k1: v1[0] for k1, v1 in v.items()}
   ...:     

In [3]: mydata
Out[3]: 
{0: {u'AM019J4O': u'XAIXMZ2H',
  u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EKDZTAZJ',
  u'CMNH1UAS': u'EP8S0STW'},
 1: {u'AM019J4O': u'X47VO9R8',
  u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EK5GPG4R',
  u'CMNH1UAS': u'RNANJHMK'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate through all nested dictionaries and extract the single elements from the lists:

```
mydata = {k: {nk: nv[0] for nk, nv in v.items()} for k, v in mydata.items()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> {k: {nk: nv[0] for nk, nv in v.items()} for k, v in mydata.items()}
{0: {u'CMNH1UAS': u'EP8S0STW', u'AM019J4O': u'XAIXMZ2H', u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EKDZTAZJ'}, 1: {u'CMNH1UAS': u'RNANJHMK', u'AM019J4O': u'X47VO9R8', u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EK5GPG4R'}}
>>> pprint(_)
{0: {u'AM019J4O': u'XAIXMZ2H',
     u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EKDZTAZJ',
     u'CMNH1UAS': u'EP8S0STW'},
 1: {u'AM019J4O': u'X47VO9R8',
     u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EK5GPG4R',
     u'CMNH1UAS': u'RNANJHMK'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
mydata = {0: {u'AM019J4O': [u'XAIXMZ2H'],
      u'BPJZMDRJ': [u'EKDZTAZJ'],
      u'CMNH1UAS': [u'EP8S0STW'],},
     1: {u'AM019J4O': [u'X47VO9R8'],
      u'BPJZMDRJ': [u'EK5GPG4R'],
      u'CMNH1UAS': [u'RNANJHMK'],}}


pprint.pprint(mydata)

def change(mydata):
    res = dict()
    for key, value in mydata.items():
        res[key] = {key: v[0] for key, v in value.items()}
    return res

pprint.pprint(change(mydata))
```

The output:

```
{0: {u'AM019J4O': u'XAIXMZ2H',
     u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EKDZTAZJ',
     u'CMNH1UAS': u'EP8S0STW'},
 1: {u'AM019J4O': u'X47VO9R8',
     u'BPJZMDRJ': u'EK5GPG4R',
     u'CMNH1UAS': u'RNANJHMK'}}
```